# Delete all rows except specifics

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a large database with 300,000 rows (1.6 GB). I need to delete them all EXCEPT the ones that has the following features:

```
main_sec=118 
main_sec=Companies
type=SWOT
```

Here is the code I prepared, but somehow, it's deleting all the rows of the table:

```
DELETE FROM `swots` 
WHERE (main_sec <> '118') OR
      (main_sec <> 'Companies') OR 
     (type <> 'SWOT');
```

Please help me to understand where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be faster to insert the rows that you want to keep (assuming they are fewer then the remaining rows) in a new table like :

```
INSERT INTO main_sec_new
SELECT
   *
FROM main_sec 
WHERE main_sec IN ('118','Companies')
and type = 'SWOT'
```

And then just drop the old table

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM `swots` 
WHERE main_sec not in ('118', 'Companies')
and type <> 'SWOT'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM `swots` 
WHERE (main_sec not in ('118', 'Companies')) OR
      (type <> 'SWOT');
```

The problem is that `main_sec` is *always* not equal to one of those two values in a given record.  So, every record meets the `where` condition in your version.

Comment: i think its `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The rows that must to be avoid of being deleted should have ANY of this 3 conditions, so OR should work properly. I'm gonna try and publish the result

Comment: I got an error:

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: @user2746655 "The rows that must to be avoid of being deleted should have ANY of this 3 conditions" you didn't specified that ANY of the conditions should be meet so we assumed that ALL should be respected. In that case `OR` is correct.